# Простой вопрос к JS скриптерам

Tags: javascript

Вот стало интересно какая разница между:

```
document['getElementById']("id"); и document.getElementById("id");
```

конкретно в производительности может, или браузерной политике.

Все;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general:

> одна лишь разница в том, что использование квадратных скобок позволяет устанавливать свойства динамически